# URI(Uniform Resource Identifier)?

Tags: android

1. What does `Uri` actually do in android?
2. ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI

   what is the purpose of `CONTENT_URI` here?
3. `Uri uri = data.getData();
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);`

   why did they use Uri here?
4. *Is there any* **substitute** *of Uri?*

*P.S I've googled it, went to AndroidDevelopers website, still confused.*

**the code for reference**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {  
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {   
            startActivityForResult(new Intent
          (Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI),PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);  
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

wasn't I supposed to put the name of a class here -> `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,`**uri**`);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does Uri actually do in android?

It does the same thing as it does on the Internet: it is an address, identifying some content. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891003/uriuniform-resource-identifier` is also a URI.

The concept of a [uniform resource identifier (URI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) has been around for a couple of decades.

> what is the purpose of CONTENT_URI here?

It is an address identifying a collection of content, specifically a collection of contacts managed by the `ContactsContract` `ContentProvider`.

> why did they use Uri here?

That `Intent` says "I want to view some content, where the content is identified by this `Uri`". We have to identify the content *somehow*, and in Android `Uri` is a standard way to identify content.

Beyond that, asking "why did Developer X choose to do Thing Y?" is not a good format for Stack Overflow. The only one who can answer that question definitively is Developer X, and Developer X is unlikely to be helping here and see your question.

> Is there any substitute of Uri?

Not in general.

> wasn't I supposed to put the name of a class here

[`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) has several constructors.

The constructor that takes a Java `Class` object as the second parameter is an "explicit `Intent`", one that identifies a particular component that you want to work with (e.g., an activity to start).

The constructor that takes an action string (e.g., `ACTION_VIEW`) and optionally a `Uri` is an "implicit `Intent`". This identifies some generic action to be performed, where Android will work to try to identify a component that can handle that action. In many cases, the action is performed against some content identified by the `Uri` (e.g., view this Web page, edit this contact).

Comment: just before you posted this answer, I almost figured out all the answers by printing the **uri** as **String** in **console**
Anyway many thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Just like a `URL`(website) a `URI` helps you to store the **ABSOLUTE PATH/LINK** of a web address or any element in your android system for instance *contact A's path*. In the above code, the URI is used to store the address(path) of the contact which you've been trying to fetch.